# What does "up the other end" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "up the other end" mean in football (soccer)?

32 minSane drops the shoulder to earn a yard of space, before sending in a decent enough cross. Mustafi was well positioned to clear it behind, however, and from the corner Kompany should have done a little better. Up the other end, Walker got a toe to the ball before Wilshere could shoo

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the transition of the ball from Arsenal's defensive half to Manchester City's defensive half.

Once Kompany missed the chance to score, Arsenal got possession of the ball, and managed to get the ball into a scoring position "*Up the other end*" of the pitch.